# How to deploy a next app on Fleek without using export to generate static HTML to not disable API Routes?

Tags: next.js, vercel, ipfs

Is there a way to deploy a next app, still have a static html file generated, without using next export so the eventual local API routes are not disabled? If no, what are the ways around it?
The reason I am asking this is that I am trying to deploy a next app on Fleek but regardless of how I set the config for the app, I end up with either my app folders displayed instead of html expected or with an error message at the end of the building process that says it could not find the public directory. Can someone assist me with this?